# How do I plot the absolute values to a geopandas world map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I am using a script to plot the population values for each country to the pandas preset lowres world map, but since its a huge scale (values between 0 and 1.2B) the countries having a 0 or NaN value look exactly the same as those with about 100k. To avoid this I wanted to plot the absolute value for each country on it's place in the map, so you can differentiate better, but I do not a have a clue of how to do it.

The interesting part of my script looks like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable    

_, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.1)
world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, cax=cax, legend=True)
plt.show()
```

The subplot is used for the colorbar.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute value? 'pop_est' is absolute value.

Comment: yeah sorry, i do not really know how to express it. pop_est is plotted on the map using a colorbar, so it is plotted as a color. But those colors are not the most specific thing and you can't really differentiate between values of 0 and 100k. So I need the value to be plotted on the map as a number as well. So the value is on the map as a color and with the value itself.

Comment: Label, you want to put labels on the map. https://github.com/shotleft/how-to-python/blob/master/How%20it%20works%20-%20labelling%20districts%20in%20GeoPandas.ipynb

Comment: Thank you! I will read through it and immediately apply to my script.